# Starred version of \captionof not working together with pdfpages

Tags: captions, pdfpages, starred-version

I use the following code to get a caption on the previous page but the correct location of the figure in the ToC. I now get 2 entries in the ToC, which is not really a surprise ;-). I now want to get rid of the first caption by using `\captionof*` instead. If I do that the `\captionof` command is ignored. I cannot find anything meaningfull in the log file also.

```
{   
\captionof{figure}
  [Organisation of the thesis (english)]
  {Organisation of the thesis (next page)} \label{fig:organisation} 
\pagebreak
\captionlistentry[figure]
  {Organisation of the thesis (english)}
\includepdf{./Bilder/organisationThesis} 
}

%\includepdf[addtolist={1000,figure,Organisation of the thesis (english),fig:organisation}]
%  {./Bilder/organisationThesis}
```

using

```
%\includepdf[addtolist={1,figure,Organisation of the thesis (english),fig:organisation}]
%  {./Bilder/organisationThesis}
```

also had no success and is likely to get the wrong pagenumber in the end.

I am compiling using `xelatex`; all packages are current TeX Live 2011 packages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to suppress the inclusion of an entry in the toc you should use an empty optional argument (assuming that my guess that you use the caption package is correct):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{caption,pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\captionof{figure}[]{Organisation of the thesis (next page)}
\label{fig:organisation}
\pagebreak
\addtocounter{figure}{-1}
\captionlistentry[figure]{Organisation of the thesis (english)}
 \includepdf{test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I wish I'd found this answer 3 hours ago...